# How to append strings inside dataframe cells based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'Col1': ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Maybe'], 'Col2': ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No'], 'Result': ''})
```

I want to populate `Result` with a list that may need to be appended based upon a column value. In this case, the parameters would be:

If the value is 'Yes' keep the current value of `Result`, if the value is 'Maybe' append 'Attention needed (insert column name)', if the value is 'No' append 'Failure (insert column name)'

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: @Josmoor98 my apologies, edited

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Also, you wrote _I want to populate Result with a list that may need to be appended based upon a column value_, but it looks like you're doing so based on multiple columns. Is that what your data actually looks like? Can you provide some context for this?

Comment: @AMC I am not trying to append strings to a series that results in a string. I need to append strings to a series that results in a list within each cell, if that is even possible.

Comment: Yes, I had misread the data, it's less than ideal but it's certainly possible.

Comment: Again, is this to be used on multiple columns? That kind of information will influence what the ideal solution is. EDIT: In fact, I'm confused as to what the use case for this is. It doesn't lead to any new information, just a slightly more awkward representation of what was already there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by 'used on multiple columns'. It would ideally be able to look across select columns I directed it to and append a list value based upon a criteria I defined. 

If needed, we can find a way to chat outside of this forum so I can better define the problem. Let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209479/discussion-between-amc-and-trace-r).

Answer (score 1):

Not very pretty, but you could create a `dict`, then use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `join` aggregation:

```
d = {'No': 'Failure', 'Maybe': 'Attention needed'}
s = df[['Col1', 'Col2']].stack().map(d).dropna()

df['Result'] = (s + ' ' + s.index.get_level_values(1)).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

[out]

```
    Col1 Col2                               Result
0     No  Yes                         Failure Col1
1    Yes   No                         Failure Col2
2     No   No           Failure Col1, Failure Col2
3  Maybe   No  Attention needed Col1, Failure Col2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one liner code using `lambda` function:

```
df['Result'] = df[['Col1','Col2']].apply(lambda x: 'Failure Col1' if (x[0]=='No' and x[1]=='Yes') else ('Failure Col2' if (x[1]=='No' and x[0]=='Yes') else ('Failure Col1, Failure Col2' if (x[0]=='No' and x[1]=='No') else("Attention needed Col1, Failure Col2" if (x[0]=='Maybe' and x[1]=='No') else None))), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Col1     Col2    Result
0   No      Yes     Failure Col1
1   Yes     No      Failure Col2
2   No      No      Failure Col1, Failure Col2
3   Maybe   No      Attention needed Col1, Failure Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may first construct the result column as a numpy array while traversing the data frame columns and checking the values then you can add the new result column and drop the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a dictionary to replace values in `df` and Using `*` and `+` to construct a series of appropriate message strings and finally join them and assign to `df.Result`

```
d = {'Yes': '', 'No': 'Failure ', 'Maybe': 'Attention needed '}
df1 = df[['Col1', 'Col2']]
df['Result'] = ((df1.replace(d) 
                + df1.ne('Yes').values * df1.columns.values).agg(','.join, axis=1)
                                                            .str.strip(','))
```

Or

```
df['Result'] = ((df1.replace(d) 
                + df1.ne('Yes').values * (df1.columns+',').values).sum(1)
                                                                  .str.strip(','))

Out[267]:
    Col1 Col2                              Result
0     No  Yes                        Failure Col1
1    Yes   No                        Failure Col2
2     No   No           Failure Col1,Failure Col2
3  Maybe   No  Attention needed Col1,Failure Col2
```

---

Here the detail

```
df1.replace(d) + df1.ne('Yes').values * df1.columns.values

Out[268]:
                    Col1          Col2
0           Failure Col1
1                         Failure Col2
2           Failure Col1  Failure Col2
3  Attention needed Col1  Failure Col2

((df1.replace(d) + df1.ne('Yes').values * df1.columns.values).agg(','.join, axis=1)
                                                             .str.strip(','))

Out[269]:
0                          Failure Col1
1                          Failure Col2
2             Failure Col1,Failure Col2
3    Attention needed Col1,Failure Col2
dtype: object
```